# How can I conditionally toggle elements based on whether or not they are currently selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to this site and to web development in general, but I am working on a project that I need a bit of help with. Please bear with me as I am still new to this so I understand my code is sloppy and probably inefficient.

I am working on a sticky header that will stay visible as you scroll down the page. In addition, as you click on the links I would like them to be highlighted and then move to a particular location on the page through a scrolling action. When you click on 1, it should be highlighted and the others should be grayed out.

Since I am using a unique shape to do this I simply used images. I do not know any better so if you have suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. However, this is not the point of my question to you all. I have already figured out how to make the on click scrolling action work, but I am stuck here trying to highlight the element that the user selects.

I would like to know how I can conditionally toggle an image based on it's current state. For instance, if you view the jsfiddle link below you will see that clicking one elements will toggle all of the others, but some of them remain grayed out and some of them will be highlighted.

I think if you see it in action you will understand my dilemma, so please find links to the demo below:

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/falco9805/hv8u00zn/1/)

Thank you!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section1").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
      });
     });

     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#section2").click(function() {
      $("#section1").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
     });
   });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section3").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section1").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
     });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section4").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section1").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section5").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section1").toggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section1text").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section2text").click(function() {
      $("#section1").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section3text").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section1").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section4text").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section1").toggle();
      $("#section5").toggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#section5text").click(function() {
      $("#section2").toggle();
      $("#section3").toggle();
      $("#section4").toggle();
      $("#section1").toggle();
    });
    });
```

Comment: use a common class so you can just toggle an active class in one event listener and prevent all that code duplication

Answer (score 1):

So manly you can do that all with this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[id^="section"]').on('click', function() {
    $('div[id^="section"]').addClass('not-active');
    $(this).removeClass('not-active');
  });
});
```

and the most important changes in CSS are like so:

```
[id^="section"] {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

[id^="section"] img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

[id^="section"].not-active img:last-child {
  display: block;
}

[id^="section"].not-active img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Ooh and big change, the active/in-active images are now all in the same div and get triggered via CSS with `first-` and `last-` child!

If something is unclear just ask in the comment section

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[id^="section"]').on('click', function() {
    $('div[id^="section"]').addClass('not-active');
   $(this).removeClass('not-active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 1596px;
}

section {
  height: ;
}

.stickybanner {
  height: 71px;
  padding-bottom: 20px
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#section1 {
  padding-bottom: 125px;
}

.bannerbg {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#banner {
  position: absolute;
}

[id^="section"] {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

[id^="section"] img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

[id^="section"].not-active img:last-child {
  display: block;
}

[id^="section"].not-active img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

#section1 {
  left: 26px;
}

#section2 {
  left: 325px;
}

#section3 {
  left: 624px;
}

#section4 {
  left: 923px;
}

#section5 {
  left: 1222px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

    <div class="stickybanner">
      <div class="bannerbg"><img src="http://imgur.com/UaZtFBu.png"></div>

      <div id="section1">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/A3hv0f3.png">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/iQv7yhd.png">
      </div>
      <div id="section2">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/Ld1TntV.png">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/oziGN60.png">
      </div>
      <div id="section3">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/zpViBoy.png">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/f5wSB6N.png">
      </div>
      <div id="section4">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/hgt5u84.png">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/Skhrull.png">
      </div>
      <div id="section5">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/iOThUy8.png">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/lLRbfvT.png">
      </div>


    </div>

  </section>
```